# Test For Number In JTEXT Fields

Tags: java, swing, parsing, try-catch

Ok so I have a Jframe with JTextFields and 2 fields that require a number format to continue. For some reason it is testing for the 2nd but not the first

```
try{

        Integer.parseInt(pin);
        t = true;
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        l_message.setText("Enter A Number In Field Pin");
        t = false;
    }
    try{

        Double.parseDouble(dep);
        t = true;
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe1){
        l_message.setText("<html>Enter A Number In<br>Field: Deposit Amount</html>");
        t = false;
    }
```

I don't know whats going on. When I enter a number for the double it will continue but no matter what it will continue the code and crash because I'm trying to send a string for the pin text field. I don't want to convert it yet because I'm testing for specifications within that field.

Can someone fix it please.

Comment: You could also have a look at [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) or even a `DocumentFilter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
try{
    Integer.parseInt(pin);
    try{
            Double.parseDouble(dep);
            t = true;
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe1){
            l_message.setText("<html>Enter A Number In<br>Field: Deposit Amount</html>");
            t = false;
    }
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
    l_message.setText("Enter A Number In Field Pin");
    t = false;
}
```

Comment: Awesome that worked didn't event think of that. I'm to tired.